# Using subquery within query to return result without variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create query that will return two results where those two results have the same unique column ID.

I have written a query that uses variables but it causes my C# application to fail.

Here is the query that I wrote that works in SQL but I am trying to use a subquery instead of SQL variables and two separate queries :

```
declare @@ItemID varchar(50) 
set @@ItemID = (select itemdie_id from TEN_Item_Die_Window
where sequence_nr = 1 and itemdiewin_w = 3.5 and itemdiewin_l = 1.25 and 
itemdiewin_left = 0 and itemdiewin_bottom = 2)

select * from TEN_Item_Die_Window
where @@ItemID = itemdie_id and sequence_nr = 2 and itemdiewin_w = 3.75 and 
itemdiewin_l = 1.25 and itemdiewin_left = .125 and itemdiewin_bottom = 0
```

Here is my original query that I am trying to modify to have a subquery (I should always get two results but I am only looking for the two where the first result equals the conditions in the where clause (from first where clause) and the second result matches the itemdie_id from the first where clause and matches the rest of the where condition from the second where clause :

```
select * from TEN_Item_Die_Window
where sequence_nr = 1 and itemdiewin_w = 3.5 and itemdiewin_l = 1.25 and 
itemdiewin_left = 0 and itemdiewin_bottom = 2 
or sequence_nr = 2 and itemdiewin_w = 3.75 and itemdiewin_l = 1.25 and 
itemdiewin_left = .125 and itemdiewin_bottom = 0
```

Here is an image of the results I am trying to get:

[image: results]

Comment: Hi @dstanton, it would be helpful if you could share a sample data and sample output for what you are looking for.

Comment: Why do you need to use a subquery if your last SQL code block works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
select
    x.*
from
    TEN_Item_Die_Window as x
    join (  select
                itemdie_id
            from
                TEN_Item_Die_Window
            where
                sequence_nr = 2
                and itemdiewin_w = 3.75
                and itemdiewin_l = 1.25
                and itemdiewin_left = .125
                and itemdiewin_bottom = 0) as y on x.itemdie_id = y.itemdie_id
where
    x.sequence_nr = 1
    and x.itemdiewin_w = 3.5
    and x.itemdiewin_l = 1.25
    and x.itemdiewin_left = 0
    and x.itemdiewin_bottom = 2 
    or  x.sequence_nr = 2
        and x.itemdiewin_w = 3.75
        and x.itemdiewin_l = 1.25
        and x.itemdiewin_left = .125
        and x.itemdiewin_bottom = 0
```

perhaps you should add another join if the row with first condition can also be skipped

```
select
    x.*
from
    TEN_Item_Die_Window as x
    join (  select
                itemdie_id
            from
                TEN_Item_Die_Window
            where
                sequence_nr = 2
                and itemdiewin_w = 3.75
                and itemdiewin_l = 1.25
                and itemdiewin_left = .125
                and itemdiewin_bottom = 0) as y on x.itemdie_id = y.itemdie_id
    join (  select
                itemdie_id
            from
                TEN_Item_Die_Window
            where
                sequence_nr = 1
                and itemdiewin_w = 3.5
                and itemdiewin_l = 1.25
                and itemdiewin_left = 0
                and itemdiewin_bottom = 2) as z on x.itemdie_id = z.itemdie_id
where
    x.sequence_nr = 1
    and x.itemdiewin_w = 3.5
    and x.itemdiewin_l = 1.25
    and x.itemdiewin_left = 0
    and x.itemdiewin_bottom = 2 
    or  x.sequence_nr = 2
        and x.itemdiewin_w = 3.75
        and x.itemdiewin_l = 1.25
        and x.itemdiewin_left = .125
        and x.itemdiewin_bottom = 0
```

another solution with window functions

```
select
    *
from
    (   select
            *,
            count(*) over(  partition by
                                itemdie_id) as rows_count
        from
            TEN_Item_Die_Window
        where
            sequence_nr = 1
            and itemdiewin_w = 3.5
            and itemdiewin_l = 1.25
            and itemdiewin_left = 0
            and itemdiewin_bottom = 2 
            or  sequence_nr = 2
                and itemdiewin_w = 3.75
                and itemdiewin_l = 1.25
                and itemdiewin_left = .125
                and itemdiewin_bottom = 0)
where
    rows_count = 2
```

Comment: Y.K. had an answer that ended up working for me. It was the first portion of code that you posted that ended up working for me. Thank you very much!!!